# Arithmetic Progression Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question is: in the sequence $5,3,-2,-5,\dots$ each term after the first two is constructed by taking the preceding term and subtracting the term before it. What is the sum of the first $32$ terms in the sequence?

Comment: FYI, that's not what "arithmetic progression" means. Did you try writing out more terms of the sequence? Even writing out all the first 32 terms shouldn't take very long. Make some effort, and then edit your question to explain the difficulty if you find any.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried, your thoughts on the problem and where you got stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: Its not homework.I tried my best but correct answer not found.

Comment: I need easy way to solve this question with common difference and sum formula method.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. We have that 
$$a_3=a_{2}-a_{1},$$
$$a_4=a_{3}-a_{2}=(a_{2}-a_{1})-a_2=-a_1,$$
$$a_5=a_{4}-a_{3}=-a_1-(a_{2}-a_{1})=-a_2,$$
$$a_6=a_{5}-a_{4}=-a_2-(-a_{1})=-a_2+a_1=-a_3.$$
Do you see any pattern?

Moreover, note that $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}-a_n=a_n-a_{n-1}-a_n=-a_{n-1}$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=27}^{32}a_k=0$$